# Most efficient way to leverage OpenCV's Transparent API for pixel operations

Tags: c++, opencv

So I might be missing something, but it seems the only way to iterate over a `cv::UMat` is first convert it to a `cv::Mat`. Is this true? I need to write many functions to operate on individual pixels. I've templatized a lot my code, but things are getting a bit convoluted because of all the switching I have to do. If I didn't have to call `mat.getMat(flag)` all over the place, that would be much better.

Thanks!

For example, I've implemented a cumulative sum:

```
cv::Mat CumSum(const cv::Mat& histogram) {
  cv::Mat cumsum =
      cv::Mat::zeros(histogram.rows, histogram.cols, histogram.type());
  cumsum.at<float>(0) = (histogram.at<float>(0));
  for (int i = 1; i < histogram.total(); ++i) {
    cumsum.at<float>(i) = cumsum.at<float>(i - 1) + histogram.at<float>(i);
  }
  return cumsum;
}
```

the `at<type>` doesn't exist for `cv::UMat` so I was forced to used function overloading instead of templatizing the in put types.

Comment: What is TAPI please?

Comment: Open cvs transparent API

Comment: From what I can tell, this will have to do with the fact that the data of the Matrix can be [stored in different types of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33614030/3962537) - system, gpu, ... Why do you need operate on individual pixels? Can you show the algorithm?